# Error in SQL Log: Timeout occurred while waiting for latch: class 'FCB', type 3,

Tags: sql-server-2014, error-log

We are running SQL Server 2014 SP2. Our server is under heavy transactional load and recently we found these messages in the SQL Server Error Log:

> Timeout occurred while waiting for latch: class 'FCB', id 000000235CA78238, type 3, Task 0x000000E5E5C284E8 : 0, waittime 7500 seconds, flags 0x2000000019, owning task 0x0000015337C37848. Continuing to wait.

When searching for this error, the closest I found is this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2545989/fix-a-time-out-occurred-while-waiting-for-buffer-latch-error-when-many), but it applies to SQL Server 2008R2 (and we don't use snapshot isolation).  Did anybody run into this on SQL Server 2014 or later and, if so, how did you resolve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a bottleneck issue. Possibly a locked record. Did you guys try killing all sessions and rerunning?

Comment: This blog post might help you, but it gets a bit complicated.  It is dealing with an earlier SQL version but still seems relevant (note your error message as compared to the ones shown on that page).  https://troubleshootingsql.com/2011/08/26/debugging-that-latch-timeout/

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a task is trying to acquire a latch (think of it as a reader-writer lock) and it's acquired by someone else. The task will wait until latch is released, which in most cases is quick. However, the task will abort after it has waited for more than 5 minutes. There are several things that could cause it, the most common being slow IO response.

Maybe this will help: https://mssqlwiki.com/2012/09/07/latch-timeout-and-sql-server-latch/